# Excel SUM current column (via Excel::Template)

Tags: perl, excel, excel-template

I'm using [Excel::Template](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Excel%3A%3ATemplate) to generate a series of Excel files via perl. However, I need to do a `SUM` function on the current Column. I know I can do

```
=SUM(3:15)
```

but that gives the sum of *ALL* columns in rows 3-15. Is there an easier way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=sum(indirect(concatenate(address(<row_start>,column()),":")&address(<row_end>,column())))
```

gives me exactly what I need. Not exactly sure how it works, but found on [MrExcel.com](http://www.mrexcel.com/archive/Formulas/27278.html)

Comment: the column() function gets the number of the current column (so if you put "=column()" as the formula for cell A3, it will be "1").  The address() function returns an excel-friendly address string based on a row and column number (3,3 -> "$D$3").  Concatenate() joins strings together (the ":" makes the first and second address into a range reference).  Indirect() changes a string like "A1:D1" to a cell/range reference of the intended string.  And finally, sum() takes the range reference and adds up the values.

Answer (score 0):

For column C,

```
=SUM(C3:C15)
```

Since =SUM(...) is just a string, you may have to parametrize the column if you don't know it before runtime. For instance

```
$str = "=SUM(" . col_char . "3:" . col_char . "15)";
```

Comment: The column character is not provided to me; otherwise, this would be a simple task.

Comment: Excel VBA has a way of determining the active workbook, active worksheet, active column and active cell. It's likely your Perl API has this too. I'm sorry, though, that I misunderstood your question.